# What is Pas Shacharis

Tags: halacha, eating, bread, morning-day

The Shulchan Aruch (155:2) writes that after the morning prayers, one should make a point to eat Pas Shacharis "Morning bread". Does anyone have a mekoros that discuss what makes up pas schacharis? is it whole grain? Or can it include even white bleached bread

Comment: In general I think "nicer" bread is considered white bread. So I'm not sure what you mean "even"...

Comment: @andrewmh20 what do you mean nicer? cleaner? more refined?

Comment: I'm saying, the more refined bread is considered "better," "higher quality" in those times. Not sure it's relevant, or maybe you knew that....just your wording confused me because of that.

Comment: @andrewmh20 Well, I don't think highly processed and bleached bread was invented in those times, also nutritionally it has very little benefit.

Comment: Right -but they did have more refined bread, and less refined bread. Even though the more refined is less healthy, they considered it higher quality.

Comment: @andrewmh20 could be, i dont know

Comment: It might be worthwhile to start looking at [Bava Metzia 107b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=107b&format=pdf), and the commentaries there.

Comment: There is mention of fine flour and coarse flour

Comment: I think Tosefos on Berachos 37b s.v. torisa d'nehama is relevant.  I can't prove it, but I assume Rabbeinu Dovid Mimetz did what he did for pas shacharis, and held it doesn't have to be hamotzi as long as it is the ingredients of bread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to R' Rabbi Moishe Dovid Lebovits

> According to the basic reading of the Shulchan Aruch it seems that one should wash for bread every morning in order to have pas shacharis.(59) However, many say one is not required to eat bread, and whatever one eats in the morning is sufficient, as long as it is filling.(60) Some say one should be careful to have a food that is mezonos.(61)
>
> Accordingly, breakfast cereals which are made from the five grains may be used as pas shacharis (i.e. Cheerios, Oatmeal, and Farina).(62) Others say having a coffee in the morning is sufficient.(63)
>
> The shiur for one who eats is a kebeitzah.(64) One who has nothing to eat can drink water.(65) Even one who is traveling should still try to have pas shacharis.(66)
>
> (59) Chucham Tzvi 15:pages 50-51 (new). (60) Eishel Avraham Butchatch 155. (61) Pri Megadim M.Z. 1, Kaf Hachaim 23, Ohr Ltzyion 2:10:6, Rivevos Ephraim 3:590:21, 35. (62) Horav Yisroel Belsky Shlita. (63) Eishel Avraham Butchatch, Kaf Hachaim 23, Minhag Yisroel Torah 155:16. Some say it is segula to remember (Piskei Teshuvos 155:footnote 58, Kuntres Zichron Shneur 70:see 58). (64) M.Z. 155:1, Kaf Hachaim 29, Refer to Biur Halacha yuchul. (65) Kaf Hachaim 29. Refer to Shar Hatzyion 155:3. (66) Toras Haderech 6:15:page 75.

[Source](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/weekly_torah.php?id=193)

Answer (score 1):

Being that I am not able to comment on other posts yet, I have to do it this way.

I once heard in the name of a well-respected Rosh Yeshiva in Eretz Yisroel that pas shacharis is whatever you need to eat in the morning, not specifically bread or bread products.

According to that, Trix could be pas shacharis.

Answer (score 0):

There are people who ritualize this in all sorts of ways -- not necessary. The point is that it's important to eat breakfast!

Comment: As the Tur says ([OC 155:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x328)), the purpose is to remain healthy and robust. However, see the Bach quoting the Mordechai, who says this refers to bread from a particular type of grain.