# Is Pas Shacharis a Chiyuv or can I skip breakfast?

Tags: halacha, food, meal-seudah, bread, morning-day

Is the mitzvah of paas shachris a chiyuv or is it halachically permissable for someone to not eat breakfast every morning?

If it is a chiyuv what is the best way and also what is the simplest way to complete the mitzvah? (Please bring sources of course)

Comment: If you are fasting half day you don't need to have *pas shacharis*.

Comment: related: [What is Pas Shacharis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53673/11501)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! Be aware you can rename your username to make it even more memorable.

Answer (score 7):

[dinonline](https://dinonline.org/2012/05/17/eating-bread-for-breakfast/) responds to your question as such

> The idea of pas shel shacharis — morning bread, or breakfast — **is not
> an “obligation,” but is stated by the Sages of the Gemara by way of
> good advice.** The Gemara writes that no less than 83 ailments are
> countered by “morning bread,” and a number of additional benefits are
> also mentioned, such as the ability to focus well on one’s studies,
> and another twelve benefits (Bava Metzia 107b).
>
> **The Tur (Orach Chaim 155) mentions the concept of eating breakfast,
> and writes that it is a mitzvah to take care of one’s body, and to
> ensure that one is strong for the service of Hashem** (see also Mishnah
> Berurah 155:11, who cites this).
>
> For deeper meaning of the matter, see the Maharal, in his Chiddushei
> Agados. See also Yaaros Devash (1:6), who explains that Chazal mean to
> teach that one should not search for pleasures, but make one’s custom
> to eat bread and water.
>
> **Therefore, although it is good practice to eat breakfast, there is no
> obligation to do so, and everything depends on personal circumstances.
> If you will feel better without eating, you should not eat.**

Comment: Perfect thanks!